# Can view HTML and PHP I wrote but install.php returns error

Tags: installation, configuration, 8

I installed Drupal8 for the first time to try things out. I used nginx and mySQL on FreeBSD with php-fpm for fastcgi. I have the nginx root set to `/usr/local/www/drupal8` cause that's where the `install.php` file is. If I put a HTML file in there, I can view it with `localhost/index.html`. If I write a little `info.php` file, it runs and shows the expected `phpinfo()` data but if I try to do `localhost/install.php`, the address bar changes to `localhost/core/install.php` and nginx returns a `502 Bad Gateway` and the nginx error log shows this:

> Call to undefined function Doctrine\Common\Annotations\token_get_all()
>   in
>   /usr/local/www/drupal8/vendor/doctrine/annotations/lib/Doctrine/Common/Annotations/TokenParser.php
>   on line 56" while reading response header from upstream, client:
>   127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /core/install.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock:", host:
>   "localhost"

I see this error in a few Google searches but the solutions are related to special programs or programmer errors. I followed directions on setting up php.ini and copied settings.php. I don't know what to do or where to look to fix this.

Comment: You've somehow ended up with a version of PHP built without [tokenizer support](http://us.php.net/manual/en/ref.tokenizer.php) (which Drupal requires). Drupal can't help you to fix that, you'll need to recompile PHP

Comment: @Clive PHP 5.6.30

Comment: I updated the comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed Drupal8 from FreeBSD ports. I don't normally use PHP for anything so PHP version 5.6.30 is what is on my computer so either that is what Drupal used or that's what the port installed. I don't know why PHP7 was not installed instead.

In FreeBSD, the tokenizer extension is not automatically installed so I added php56-tokenizer and now Drupal8 works.